# How can we calculate the time of operation between each start and stop in node red for a conveyor belt using now() funcion?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am trying to calculate the start and stop time for a conveyor belt system using a function NODE by writing some java Script code to record the time of start and time of stop in variables.

```
var d = Date.now(); //to store current time in milliseconds where d holds current time in milliseconds
```

Comment: when your function finished execution subtract from current time `d`  variable you created in the beginning of the function execution.  `Date.now() - d`

Comment: Can you please give me the Java script code so i can try it in my system. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What Node Red nodes have you got so far, and between which ones do you want to measure the time? it's not clear if this is all in one `function` node (which would be trivial to just subtract two Date objects) or if it's between the start of one node and the end of another (in which case it's still a subtract, but you need to persist the start time in the message or global/flow context).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an npm package that will display the ellapsed time between tic() and toc() function calls.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tictoc

Answer (score 0):

You have to store lastConveyorStatus and lastStartTimetamp in global context, I suppose that the status of the conveyor is provided in `msg.payload.status` :

```
const lastConveyorStatus = global.get('lastConveyorStatus') ¦¦ false;

if (msg.payload.status && !lastConveyorStatus) {
  // the conveyor has just started to run
  global.set('lastStartTimestamp', Date.now());

}else if (!msg.payload.status && lastConveyorStatus) {
  // the conveyor has just stopped running 
  const lastStartTimestamp = global.get('lastStartTimestamp') ¦¦ Date.now(); // in case of node-RED restart or other
  msg.payload.lastRunDuration = Date.now() - lastStartTimestamp;
  global.set('lastStopTimestamp', Date.now()); // for other usage ?

}

// update the status of the conveyor in global store
global.set('lastConveyorStatus', msg.payload.status');

return msg;
```

Hope it helps :-)